# Multiprocessing: cannot share a variable between files

Tags: python, multiprocessing, global-variables, python-import

I describe my issue with a minimal example. In my project a `config` file contains a variable `param` which is used by all other modules:

```
# config.py
param = -1
```

The `config` is imported in `solver` which performs a computation based on the passed `val` and the `param` from config:

```
# solver.py
import config

def solve(val):
    # some computation using val and config.param
    print('solver uses param:', config.param)
    return None
```

My goal is to perform the computation for some `param` and various `val`s.

```
# main.py
import multiprocessing as mp
import config, solver

val_list = [None for i in range(3)]
pool = mp.Pool(10)
config.param = 1
print('testing param: ', config.param)
results = pool.map(solver.solve, [val for val in val_list]) # multiprocessing
#results = [solver.solve(val) for val in val_list]          # basic
```

While using multiprocessing I get an output:

```
testing param:  1
solver uses param: -1
solver uses param: -1
solver uses param: -1
```

which means that the change of `param` in `main` isn't seen by `solver`. However, it is seen when using basic for-loop computation:

```
testing param:  1
solver uses param: 1
solver uses param: 1
solver uses param: 1
```

How can I get the desired behavior with multiprocessing? Note that the change of `param` shouldn't be done manually in `config`, as in reality I test different values of `param` in a for-loop. I am using Python 3.6.9 on Linux. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override config.param value, before `mp.Pool()` initiate like below.

```
# main.py
import multiprocessing as mp
import config, solver

config.param = 1 # trick is that

val_list = [None for i in range(3)]
pool = mp.Pool(10)
print('testing param: ', config.param)
results = pool.map(solver.solve, [val for val in val_list]) # multiprocessing
#results = [solver.solve(val) for val in val_list]          # basic
```

Answer (score 1):

the moment you call `mp.Pool(10)` you create 10 new processes that are in "wait mode" until you give them something to run, but they already forked out of your process so any change to a local variable won't affect them

if you want to pass information to them you either need to:

pass it to them when you call them (just adding something like `pool.map(solver.solve, [(val, config.param) for val in val_list]` and then having `solve` split those arguments)

or you need to make `config.param` a variable that can be shared between processes possibly using `multiprocessing.Value` like this:

```
# config.py
import multiprocessing as mp
param = mp.Value("i", -1)
```

then you can access the value like this: `config.param.value`

Answer (score 0):

We need getter and setter method inside `solver.py` to take care the consistency of `param` value.

```
#solver.py

import config

class Solver:
    def __init__(self):
        self._config = config.param

    @property
    def config(self):
        return self._config

    @config.setter
    def config(self, cfgval):
         self._config = cfgval

    def solve(self, val):
         # some computation using val and config.param
         print('solver uses param:', self.config)
         return None
```

Then you can perform the computation for some `param` and various `val` as expected in `main.py`.

```
# main.py

import multiprocessing as mp
from solver import Solver


if __name__ == '__main__':
    val_list = [None for i in range(3)]
    pool = mp.Pool(10)
    solver = Solver()
    solver.config = 1
    results = pool.map(solver.solve, [val for val in val_list])  # multiprocessing
```